# why my setTimeOut gives me Proxy Object in Mobx, react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generator

I'm using flow function in Mobx to process asynchronous actions.

Here is usage of flow function, and each `fetchMessage`, observable variable shows me Proxy Object which is not attempt to get.

```
// I'm using mobx v6
import { observable, flow, makeObservable } from "mobx";

const getDummyMessages = () =>{
return ([
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "one",
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    text: "two",
  },
}; 

class ChatStore {

 @observable chatMessages = [];

 constructor(){
  makeObservable(this);
 }

 fetchMessage = flow( function * () {
   this.chatMessages = Promise.resolve(() => setTimeout(() => getDummyMessages(),300));
 }
}
```

I call `fetchMessage` in some functinal component like

```
 const {chatStore} = useStores();  // which get mobxStores.
 
...
 useEffect(() => {
   chatstore.fetchMessage(); 
 },[]);
```

but after call above `fetchMessage`,
chatMessages type shows

```
chatMessages: Proxy
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Array(0)
  [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

why my function gives me Proxy type ? and what is Proxy type?

Answer (score 0):

after tying different approach via `new Promise((resolve) => ...)`,
I found the way to fix this.

```
const fetchMessage = yield new Promise(
        (resolve) => setTimeout(() => {resolve(getDummyMessages())},600)
)
```

that works, but still gives me type of `Proxy`. weird.. any documentation for these `Proxy` type? never seen this before.

Comment: Here https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Proxy